# What does it mean to put DataMemberAttribute on interface member?

Tags: c#, interface, datacontract, datamember

What does it mean to put a [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) on an interface member?
How does this affect derived classes?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As shown in the following signature, the DataMember attribute is not inheritable

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property|AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false, 
    AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DataMemberAttribute : Attribute
```

Therefore, it makes very little sense to decorate interface members with this attribute as you will have to decorate the implementing classes' members with this attribute too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use this attributes with my WCF services. When I make an interface for a WCF Webservice I do it defining an interface in this way:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IClientContract

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetClientList() As IList(Of POCOClients)

End Interface
```

As you can see, the clien of this service will receive a POCOCLient class. Then  I need to decorate the POCOClient class with the attributes you're asking form in this way in order to let the class to be serialized properly and send vía WCF.

```
<DataContract()>
<MetadataType(GetType(POCOAuthorizedkeys.POCOAuthorizedkeysMetaData))>
Public Class POCOAuthorizedkeys

    <DataMember()>
    <DisplayName("Id")>
    Public Property Id As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    <DisplayName("IdPackage")>
    Public Property IdPackage As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    <DisplayName("AuthorizedKey")>
    Public Property AuthorizedKey As String
    <DataMember()>
    <DisplayName("IdUnthrustedClient")>
    Public Property IdUnthrustedClient As Nullable(Of Integer)

 End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

The [DataMember] attribute, when applied to a member of a type, specifies that the member is part of a data contract. When this attribute is applied to a field or a property explicitly, it specifies that the member value will be serialized by an DataContractSerializer object (taken from [Article](http://www.ucertify.com/article/what-is-the-datamember-attribute.html))