# Can you use interfaces as DataMembers in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

Can you do this?

```
[DataContract]
public class RegisterEndpointRequest : NotificationRegistrationServiceRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEndpoint Endpoint { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the member Endpoint is an interface (`IEndpoint`), not a class. Will WCF allow this?

Comment: I *think* it will, as long as whatever concrete `IEndpoint` implementation you have for your `Endpoint` property is also decorated with a `DataContractAttribute` and appropriate `DataMemberAttribute`s on its members. **EDIT**: Plus what [Aasmund said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11800139/74757) about the `KnownTypeAttribute`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataContractAttribute in WCF is not intended for use on an interface: [See the documentation here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)

The [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791968/) may give you a better idea why.

Comment: He's applying `[DataContract]` to a class, and `[DataMember]` to a property.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can (but I haven't tested it), but you will then need to declare all implementations of that interface with `[KnownType]`:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(EndpointImplA))]
[KnownType(typeof(EndpointImplB))]
public class RegisterEndpointRequest : NotificationRegistrationServiceRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEndpoint Endpoint { get; set; }
}
```

Each implementing class must have a `[DataContract]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can have interface as DataMember inside DataContract.. 
Then you have to have specify all the **interface implementations** in the KnownType attributes...

```
 [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(ActivityDC))]
    [KnownType(typeof(StepDC))]
    [KnownType(typeof(WaveDC))]
    public class CampaignDC : AuditedEntityBaseDC
    {
        [DataMember]
        public IList<IActivityDC> Activities { get; set; }
```